# Template Driven Form with Component - Passing state of the form to another component

Tags: angular

Well, I want to use Template Driven Form... 
And the problem is, I have the form in one component and then I call this component inside the modal, but I need to pass the state of the form for the Modal to validate the button.

My Form Component:

```
<form #form="ngForm" novalidate>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label>Descrição:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Descrição" required
                [(ngModel)]="selectedVendedorAcao.descricao">
    </div>
</form>
```

My Modal in the Page:

```
<p-dialog *ngIf="selectedVendedorAcao != null && selectedVendedorAcao.vm != null" header="Informações da Ação"
      [(visible)]="OpenModal" [baseZIndex]="2001" [style]="{ width: '40%'}">

  <app-vendedor-acao-modal
    [(tipoAcaoVendedor)]="tipoAcaoVendedor" 
    [(statusAcao)]="statusAcao"
    [(selectedVendedorAcao)]="selectedVendedorAcao">
  </app-vendedor-acao-modal>

  <p-footer>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" (click)="OpenModal = false">Cancelar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" *ngIf="selectedVendedorAcao.id == null" (click)="Upsert()">Salvar</button>
  </p-footer>

</p-dialog>
```

So, I need to get the `#Form` (`form.valid`) and send to the modal. So that way I can put some validation on the button "Salvar" (`[disabled]="!form.valid"`)

Comment: Why you cannot pass the form as a props to Modal?

Comment: Actually isn't my project. I'm just in charge of doing the validations. So I'm trying to do without changing anything like passing the form to the Modal, like you suggested. But thanks anyway. If there isn't any other option I'll talk to the person in charge to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Angular @Input() operator in the modal. You can pass the form down in the parent component, and then in the child modal component just import the form using the @Input operator.

Parent Component .html

```
<child-component [formValues]="ngForm"></child-component>
```

Child Component .ts

```
@Input formValues: any
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying this approch, but with two way binding...
But I keep getting this error "There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "form" " and I'm going to use it to validade the button, since I'm only passing the form to the child and not getting back the information if it's valid or not.

Comment: Why are you using two way binding in the parent component? If you need have the modal as part of the form in the parent component, I'd suggest creating a separate form for that modal, then make that modal form a child of the parent form and nest it.